# Create Query without entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following code, but I can’t work out what I need to put in place of the // before `.AddObject(Model);` and `.SaveChanges();` to get the method to work. It’s a create query but I’ve only ever done this while using the Entity Framework before now, in this case I’m not using EF.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Registration(UserDetailModel Model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Model.UserNameFK = User.Identity.Name;
        Model.CompanyName = "CompanyName";
        Model.IEMI = "IEMI";

        //.AddObject(Model);
        //.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Registration", "Home");
    }

    return View(Model);
}
```

Am I close?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you know Entity Framework is an [Object Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) framework for .NET.

Basically it creates entity classes that map up to your database and make it easy to perform Create/Read/Update/Delete operations without writing any SQL.

If you're not using Entity Framework, you could use another ORM like [NHinbernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx).

OR

You could use plain ADO.NET classes with SQL to write/read data to/from your database.

Ex: If you're using **SQL Server** you would use the System.Data.SqlClient namespace for writing to your SQL DB, [see the SQLCommand class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) (Writing to other supported DB's work the same way)

You would do something like this with the function below it:

```
CreateCommand(//just as an example you can use values from your model in sql
"INSERT INTO Users(Name, CompnayName, IMEI,) VALUES ("
         + Model.UserNameFK +", val2, val3,...)", 
"your connection string"
);

private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

[See this for more documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

Comment: I have used the Entity Framework many, many times! It’s slow, I am trying to do this without it. I am trying to use what has been built for me, by extending the AccountModel but the more I learnm the more I see that the built for you AccountModel is useless. All I want is a way for people to login and for me to keep track of them.

Comment: Or you you mean the `UserDetailModel` ? Anyway, whatever model it can be used to get your values from the form into your controller from there on your can do whatever you want from it. Like I described in my answer you can manually run SQL against your database instead of using entity framework. I updated my answer.